# Parameter interceptor not working in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, parameters, jboss, cdi, interceptor

In Java EE, I'm trying to call an interceptor when a method param has a specific annotation. This is the code I have:

**Annotation's Code**

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface Token{
   //NOP
}
```

**Interceptor's code**

```
@Interceptor
public class TokenInterceptor{

   @AroundInvoke
   public Object checkInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
       //Actual Code that detects the presence of the annotation
   }

}
```

**Method with annotated parameter**

```
public void processOrders(@Token List<Order> token) {}
```

**beans.xml**

```
<interceptors>
    <class>com.project.security.TokenInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

When I try to deploy my JBoss server the error below arises.

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000069 An interceptor must have at least one binding, but com.project.security.TokenInterceptor has none
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.(InterceptorImpl.java:72)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.of(InterceptorImpl.java:59)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.createInterceptor(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:229)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.createBeans(BeanDeployer.java:149)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:204)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:349)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
>       ... 3 more

Any ideas of what I'm missing to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have binding for every Interceptor like this

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

Than interceptor itself needs to be annotated with your binding

```
@Interceptor
@Logged
public void TokenInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object checkInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //Actual Code that detects the presence of the annotation
    }
}
```

Now you can bind your interceptor to any method or class using the `@Logged` annotation

```
@Logged
public void processOrders(List<Order> token) {}
```

See official Java EE tutorial [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhjx.html).

Comment: the code you included is for a method interceptor. In my case it is a `@Target(PARAMETER)`. I want to avoid, if possible, to make a `@Target({METHOD, TYPE})`